# How to keep scnr.hasNext() true

Tags: java, while-loop, int, java.util.scanner

I am debugging a part of my code that I have realized isn't working how I want it. I want to enter a couple numbers and have `int var` store them one by one, and keep `scnr.hasNext()` true if there were more numbers inputted, so that my while loop continues and I can run operations on every number.

```
public static Number evaluateExpression(String expr) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(expr);    
int var = 0;
while (scnr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scnr.hasNext());
    var = scnr.nextInt();
    System.out.println(scnr.hasNext());
}
```

Currently if I give it input of 5, 4, the output is true false false, so `var = scnr.nextInt();` is making `(scnr.hasNext());` false. How do I fix that? I also need a way to store the next scnr value if it is a string too, so

```
String input = "";
input = scnr.next();
```

would keep `scnr.hasNext()` true if there is more input given.

Comment: so the input to the evaluateExpression method would be comma separated list of numbers ? like "5,4,3" etc ?

Comment: No they are separated by a space, like 5 4 7 + -

Comment: I'm thinking maybe can use 'String[] values = expr.split(" ")' to get them into an array and then process each input using  for each loop.